# Trying to insert data into database after uploading image, syntax error in ASP Classic and VBscript

Tags: sql, vbscript, asp-classic

I am trying to insert a record into access database after uploading an image.  The image save correctly but I cant get the insert command to work.

```vbs
set o = new clsUpload
if o.Exists("cmdSubmit") then

    'get client file name without path
    sFileSplit = split(o.FileNameOf("txtFile"), "\")
    sFile = sFileSplit(Ubound(sFileSplit))

    o.FileInputName = "txtFile"
    o.FileFullPath = Server.MapPath("ads") & "\" & sFile
    o.save

    if o.Error = "" then
        response.write "Success. File saved to  " & o.FileFullPath & ". County = " &        o.ValueOf("County")

        Company = o.ValueOf("Company") 
        County = o.ValueOf("County")
        imgfile = sFile

        Set OBJdbConnection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
        OBJdbConnection.Open "PROVIDER=MICROSOFT.JET.OLEDB.4.0;DATA SOURCE=C:\Users\User\Desktop\Websites\123justlistit\wwwroot\admin\123justlistit.mdb"

        Set sqlIns = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
        sqlIns.ActiveConnection = OBJdbConnection
        sqlIns.commandtext="insert into ads (company, county, image)values(?,?,?)"
        sqlIns.Parameters.Append sqlIns.CreateParameter("@company", adVarChar, adParamInput, 25, Company)
        sqlIns.Parameters.Append sqlIns.CreateParameter("@county", adVarChar, adParamInput, 25, County)
        sqlIns.Parameters.Append sqlIns.CreateParameter("@imgfile", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, imgfile)

        sqlIns.execute
        OBJdbConnection.Close

    else
        response.write "Failed due to the following error: " & o.Error
    end if

end if
set o = nothing
```

I am getting:

```
Microsoft JET Database Engine error '80040e14'
Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.
```

I think it has something to do with trying to insert the filename of the image but I am not sure

Comment: Do you need a space before `values`? Are you sure `imgfile` is 50 chars or less?

Comment: I tried adding the space and making it 255 to match the database field and it the same error

Comment: I only see you are missing `sqlIns.CommandType = adCmdText` (where adCmdText = `&H0001`). Have you tried running the sql outside the app to check for DB errors?

Answer (score 0):

Two of your parameter names (`@company` and `@county`) conflict with column names. Either change the parameter names to something different or (better) put the identifiers in your query string in square brackets:

```
sqlIns.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [ads] ([company], [county], [image]) VALUES (?,?,?)"
```

Using square brackets also avoids problems with identifiers containing spaces or conflicting with reserved words.

Comment: After adding the brackets to my insert i am getting a type mismatch on the execute command.  my datatypes in database are text

Comment: @adgoodso23 Try inserting each column separately to isolate the value causing the issue. Then check the value that causes the error.

Comment: I believe "image" is a reserved word.  See this listing http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/sql-reserved-words-HP001032249.aspx.  This can cause problems.  Reserved keywords should not be used as names for columns, tables, aliases, or other user-defined objects

Comment: @Dee True, but putting the identifier in square brackets should take care of that.